# Function to extract all records for a specific year into a separate sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a list of students in order from 1-1000. I want to pull students from the list by year of graduation. So:

```
      A          B       C          D 
1 Book Number  First    last     yr grad 
2     1        John      Doe      2016 
3     2        Martha    Jones    2018 
4     3        Kary      Smith    2019 
5     4        Harry     Goetz    2017 
6     5        Sam       Smith    2016
```

What I need to do is write a function that will pull all the 2016 out and place them on another sheet by themselves.

Comment: Have you looked at the built-in [Advanced Filter](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b) command? It has a "Copy to another location" option which should achieve what you're looking for

Comment: @barrowc - I don't believe that the Advanced Filter will not copy to another worksheet.

Comment: @Jeeped You are quite correct - it's an annoying limitation. You could Advanced Filter to somewhere on the same sheet then copy/paste the filter results to a different worksheet, I suppose

Answer (score 1):

I'll put everything on one worksheet for demonstration purposes but you should have no trouble transcribing the formula to another worksheet.

[image: Filtered Students]

The formula in F5 is,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$9999, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$9999)/($D$1:$D$9999=$F$3), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

Fill both right and down to catch all filtered values.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a PivotTable, since might appreciate its versatility for 1,000 student records. Put all columns into ROWS other than `yr grad` in FILTERS. Then select your year (or years) and drill down by clicking on the `Grand Total`.